# How to check if a matrix is unitary?

Tags: matrices, unitary-matrices

If I have the matrix for example:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

So we need to check whether $A A^* = A^* A = I$. Is it right?

Comment: It needs a $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Alternatively (in the strictly non-complex case) you can check that $x \mapsto Ax$ is an isometry in the euclidian norm, the columns (or rows) form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ or that $A^*$ is unitary.

Comment: The matrix that I show for example is Unitary or not? And how we check that because the result of $AA^*$ is not $I$

Comment: It is not unitary, because the rows have norm $\sqrt{2} \neq 1$. You should also be able to just compute $AA^*$.